# sort with SELECT drop down asc desc connecting to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to create a drop-down list to display vehicles that are on "special" on my web browser that are from my database. I would like them to display in price order of asc to desc. I have the coding of the list but for some reason when you click on the display results it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```html
<form method="post" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' >
<select name="sort">
<option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
<option value="DESC">Descending</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="update" value= "Display results">
 </form>

<?php
// set initial value for variables to avoid errors the first time the page runs
$sort_name = "ASC";
$price="price";
// check to see if the form value has been set and if so return the value
if(isset($_POST['sort'])) {
// set the variable to the value selected from the dropdown - either ASC or DESC
$sort_name = $_POST['sort'];
}

// create the query inserting the value for the sort order with the variable $sort_name
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE special='yes'ORDER BY $price ASC";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );
if(!$results) {
echo ("Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else {
// fetch and display results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<p>VIN_#: $row[vin]</p> "; 
echo "<p>Stock Number: $row[stockno]</p> ";
echo "<p>Manufacturer Number: $row[man_num]</p>";
echo "<p>Model: $row[model]</p>";
echo "<p>Colour: $row[col_id]</p>";
echo "<p>Year: $row[year]</p>";
echo "<p>Price: $row[price]</p>";
echo "<p>Kilometres: $row[kms] </p>";
echo "<p>Registration: $row[rego] </p>";
echo "<p>Cylinders: $row[cylinders] </p>";
echo "<p>Fuel: $row[fuel] </p>";
echo "<p>Transmission: $row[transmission] </p>";
echo "<p>Category Id: $row[cat_id] </p>";
echo "<p>Vehicle on Special (yes/no): $row[special] </p>";
echo "<p>Standard Used Vehicle: $row[standardusedvehicle] </p>";
echo '<img src="'.$row[vehicle_image] . "\" >";
}
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE special='yes'ORDER BY $price ASC";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );
if(!$results) {
echo ("Query error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else {
// fetch and display results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo "<p>VIN_#: $row[vin]</p> "; 
echo "<p>Stock Number: $row[stockno]</p> ";
echo "<p>Manufacturer Number: $row[man_num]</p>";
echo "<p>Model: $row[model]</p>";
echo "<p>Colour: $row[col_id]</p>";
echo "<p>Year: $row[year]</p>";
echo "<p>Price: $row[price]</p>";
echo "<p>Kilometres: $row[kms] </p>";
echo "<p>Registration: $row[rego] </p>";
echo "<p>Cylinders: $row[cylinders] </p>";
echo "<p>Fuel: $row[fuel] </p>";
echo "<p>Transmission: $row[transmission] </p>";
echo "<p>Category Id: $row[cat_id] </p>";
echo "<p>Vehicle on Special (yes/no): $row[special] </p>";
echo "<p>Standard Used Vehicle: $row[standardusedvehicle] </p>";
echo '<img src="'.$row[vehicle_image] . "\" >";
}
}
?>
```

I have connected to my database earlier in my coding

Any Ideas would be great

Comment: Any error with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql statement is currently sorting `ASC` and is rigidly typed, try instead to use the value that is sent by the form submission

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE special='yes'ORDER BY {$price} {$_POST['sort']}";
```

The code is however vulnerable to sql injection so you would be better looking at using prepared statements

The code you posted had a few errors - each field in the html output needs to be quoted otherwise PHP will assume you are using `constants` and will throw an error. The image was not correctly using single and double quotes.

```
<form method="post" action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' >
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
        <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value= "Display results">
</form>


<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $sort_name = isset( $_POST['sort'] ) && in_array( strtolower( $_POST['sort'] ), array( 'asc','desc' ) ) ? $_POST['sort'] : 'ASC';
        $price="price";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE special='yes' ORDER BY {$price} {$sort_name}";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query );
        if( !$results ) {
            echo ("Query error: ");
        } else {
            /*
                The fields must be quoted otherwise they will be treated as constants, most likely undefined
            */
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                echo "
                <p>VIN_#: {$row['vin']}</p>
                <p>Stock Number: {$row['stockno']}</p>
                <p>Manufacturer Number: {$row['man_num']}</p>
                <p>Model: {$row['model']}</p>
                <p>Colour: {$row['col_id']}</p>
                <p>Year: {$row['year']}</p>
                <p>Price: {$row['price']}</p>
                <p>Kilometres: {$row['kms']}</p>
                <p>Registration: {$row['rego']}</p>
                <p>Cylinders: {$row['cylinders']}</p>
                <p>Fuel: {$row['fuel']}</p>
                <p>Transmission: {$row['transmission']}</p>
                <p>Category Id: {$row['cat_id']}</p>
                <p>Vehicle on Special (yes/no): {$row['special']}</p>
                <p>Standard Used Vehicle: {$row['standardusedvehicle']}</p>
                <img src='{$row['vehicle_image']}' />";/* The image was not correctly set using single quotes */
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

If you are going to use `PHP_SELF` as the form action ( or at all in your code ) you really ought to try to make it safe from XSS attacks - or use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead. That said, try using:

```
<?php
    $action = htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
?>

<form method="post" action='<?php echo action; ?>' >
```

Comment: It didn't work it came up with: Notice: Undefined variable: query in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taylor_callaghan_wca/specials.php on line 98

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/taylor_callaghan_wca/specials.php on line 98
Query error:

Comment: there is now the problem that it is not reading the data from the database

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake it is now working, thank you so much

Comment: Glad that you got it sorted eventually - good luck with the rest